# Could not write JSON: Failed making field 'java.time.Instant#seconds' accessible

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, kubernetes, gson

I have an app, locally everything is okay when I run it. I just upgraded to Spring Boot 3 version, and after this, the app is on a K8s pod. The pod keeps restarting again and again with this error:

> ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
> Could not write JSON: Failed making field 'java.time.Instant#seconds'
> accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom
> TypeAdapter for its declaring type.

I wrote a type adapter for this and tried the solutions from Stack Overflow, but I am encountering the same error. The app starts locally, but on Kubernetes (k8s), it does not. The type adapter looks like this:

```java
public class InstantAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Instant> {
    
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Instant value) throws IOException {
        out.value(value.getEpochSecond());
    }
    
    @Override
    public Instant read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        long seconds = in.nextLong();
        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds);
    }
}
```

Update:

```
 public static String toJSon(Object obj) {
    return getGson().toJson(obj);
}
 public static Gson getGson() {

    return getGsonBuilder()
            .create();
}



public static GsonBuilder getGsonBuilder() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .serializeNulls()
                .setDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT)
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GsonBaseDTOTypeAdapterFactory())
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GsonNullableTypeAdapterFactory())
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GsonAtomicReferenceTypeAdapterFactory())
                .registerTypeAdapter(ResponseEntity.class, new HttpStatusCodeInterfaceAdapter())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, new InstantAdapter())
                .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new GsonAnnotationExcludeSerializationStrategy())
                .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new GsonAnnotationExcludeDeserializationStrategy());
    }
```

What should I do to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Which framework is used for the JSON serialisation? We are using jackson and there is a `JavaTimeModule` that can be registered to the `ObjectMapper` that contains several serialisers for this, including `Instant` types. (see com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310)

Comment: Please include the code, which registers your adapter to the Gson instance. And how are you using Gson, is it a spring bean?

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:kubernetes], but is it actually specific to this environment?  Does `docker run` the image have the same problem?  `./gradlew bootRun` without a container at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze if I run the container everything it's ok and the app is starting without problems

Comment: @EugenGîrlescu The configuration seems fine. Could some of the type adapter factories be interfering with the InstantAdapter somehow (that's a stretch, I know, but I'm running out of ideas)?

Comment: Please check the stack trace whether the exception really occurs when using your custom `Gson` instance; maybe Spring is using its default configured `Gson` instance and you have to use `GsonBuilderCustomizer`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68647963